# Want to convert 3 rows in 3 columns with inner join in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, rows

I have a result set like this

[image]

And query for this result set is

```
SELECT 
    dt.GangName, u.UserFullName,dt.Designation, v.RegNo, 
    dt.SignInTime, dt.SignOutTime, z.ZoneName
FROM 
    DutyRoosterTeam dt
INNER JOIN 
    DutyRooster dr ON dr.DutyRoosterID = dt.DutyRoosterID
INNER JOIN 
    Users u ON u.UserId = dt.UserID
INNER JOIN 
    Vehicle v ON v.VehicleId = dt.MTLID
INNER JOIN 
    Zone z ON z.ZoneId = dt.ZoneID
```

But I want result set like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My copy-pasta-fu is strong.  Take a look at the solution provided by bluefeet here:

[Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server?answertab=active#tab-top)